# Remove duplicate objects from object array

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have a list of arrays i need to hide the duplicates of array

```
   {
        "company_name": "SERVICE INDUSTRIES LTD.",
        "claim_id": "2017\/04\/LHRHHDP00015-2018-00702",         
    },
    {

        "company_name": "KARACHI CHAMBER OF COMMERCE & INDUSTRY",
        "claim_id": "2018\/03\/HOHHDP00013-2019-00098",

    },
    {
        "company_name": "PAKISTAN RED CRESCENT SOCIETY",
        "claim_id": "2017\/04\/LHRHHDP00015-2018-00702",

    },
    {
        "company_name": "SERVICE INDUSTRIES LTD.",
        "claim_id": "2018\/04\/LHRHHDP00022-2019-01292",     
    },
    {
        "company_name": "U MICROFINANCE BANK LTD",
        "claim_id": "2017\/04\/LHRHHDP00015-2018-00702",    
    }
```

This is the example array i need to hide the array which have duplicate claim_id.

Comment: I already check this question but they are filtering  simple values in filter . I need to filter it by claim_id.

Comment: This is indeed not a duplicate, I've reopened it

Comment: @PierreDuc Note that the question linked as dup has indeed answers that generalize the approach to allow the selection of a "key" value...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I tried to look for them there, couldn't find it. Maybe you can link an answer in the comments

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57040361/5394220

Comment: @Jota.Toledo although that is an answer, it's not upvoted a lot, and quite complex for what's required here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `filter` and `findIndex` to find duplicates. If the index does not equal the current item, there is a duplicate.

The performance impact is maximum 1.5x the size of the array:

```
const unique = data.filter((item, index) => 
  data.findIndex(({ claim_id }) => item.claim_id === claim_id) === index
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this easily let's use this strategy:

- Extract values from the array to an object (used as a dictionary)
- Eliminating duplication
- Extract values to a new array

so....

```
const dic = {}

for (const item of originalArray) {
    dic[item.claim_id] = item
}

const groupedArray = Object.values(dic)
```

The only question is... where's typescript? we used native JS and managed just fine :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think this code doubled the arrays. Mean i have 13701 arrays after using this code its showing above 20,000 arrays

Comment: you should update your question and add the code you applied so it will be as clear as possible what exactly what's going on